# SAS - Proc Report - Don't summarize column in subtotal line?

Tags: sas, summarization, proc-report

I'm trying to accomplish the following using proc report and I have no idea how to do so.

I have proc report basically creating a spreadsheet that looks like this, grouped by ACCT and SEQ:

```
ACCT    SEQ     FMTHS     WCP
1234     1        5       1,000
                  8       1,000
                  4       1,000
--------------------------------
1234     1       17
```

However, the client wants the value of the WCP column to be shown in the subtotal line, NOT summarized. While it would make sense for WCP to display 3,000 above, they want to see 1,000. So essentially I need to end up with this:

```
ACCT    SEQ     FMTHS     WCP
1234     1        5       1,000
                  8       1,000
                  4       1,000
--------------------------------
1234     1       17       1,000
```

Here is my code so far:

```
proc report data = test missing nowindows;
        columns acct
                seq
                fmths
                wcp
                ;

    define acct /   group
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define seq /    group 
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define fmths /  analysis
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define wcp /    display  format=dollar12.
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    title; 

  break after seq/ summarize ;
  compute after seq;
  line @1 ' ';
  endcomp;

run;
```

**Update:** This sort of fixes the problem...

```
proc report data = test missing nowindows;
        columns acct
                seq
                fmths
                wcp
                ;

    define acct /   group
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define seq /    group 
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define fmths /  analysis
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define wcp /    group  format=dollar12.
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    title; 

  break after wcp/ summarize ;
  compute after wcp;
  line @1 ' ';
  endcomp;

run;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible in `PROC REPORT` without going to drastic lengths.  Certainly would love to see it if so.

Comment: Well, I sort of accomplished this. It's probably not the best solution, but it'll have to work for now...see my change above.

Answer (score 1):

This works, you simply need to duplicate FMTHS into a new variable prior to the PROC REPORT, in this example `FMTHS2 = FMTHS ;` You may be able to achieve the same result using an alias in your column statement.

```
proc report data=mydata ;
  column ACCT
         SEQ
         FMTHS
         FMTHS2
         WCP
         ;
  define ACCT   / group ;
  define SEQ    / group ;
  define WCP    / analysis mean ;
  define FMTHS  / order order=data group noprint ;
  define FMTHS2 / analysis sum ;

  break after SEQ / summarize ;
run ;
```

Comment: You can duplicate your variable within `proc report`: `column ACCT SEQ FMTHS  FMTHS = FMTHS2  WCP;`